# React music player Switching from mouse eventListener to window eventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im making a simple music player, and the problem im facing is that the player has a progress bar, however on mousemove, if i drag outside of its parent container, it loses focus. My idea was to listen to the window instead which kinda worked, but now it listens to any kind of mouseevents, like the play/pause etc.

Can i switch to a window event listener on mouseleave for example, or do anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Some of the code i used, the innerProgressbar is the line that i can drag, and also updates for the song time. The outerProgress is its parent container, which is 6px in height.

```
  mouseMove = (e) => {
    if(this.songSeeking){
    const{ song } = this.state;
    let mouseX = e.clientX - this.outerProgress.offsetLeft;
    let newTime = mouseX * song.duration/ this.outerProgress.offsetWidth;
    song.currentTime = newTime;
    this.innerProgress.style.width = mouseX + 'px';
  }
}



mousedown = (e) => {
const { song } = this.state;
if(!this.songSeeking){
  this.songSeeking = true;
  song.pause();
  this.setState({playing: false});
}



mouseup = (e) => {
  const { song } = this.state;
  if(this.songSeeking){
    this.songSeeking = false
    song.play();
    this.setState({playing: true});
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing all this state management, I would recommend using an input[type="range"] and listen for onChange value. It can be styled too: https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

Comment: I read that aswell, but  i think it has problems with browser capability. I feel im just missing some small line of code to get it working though. Everything else is working properly except when the mouse leaves

Comment: In your case you would have to listen to mouse move on the window. Because otherwise you won't be able to capture events. To your point of browser compatibility, that may be true, however when you implement custom controls such as this slider, you are going to have accessibility problems. Are you using some kind of a ui components lib? Checkout https://github.com/react-component/slider

Comment: Hi, you could say that im trying to replicate the progress bar that spotify that they use, so when they do a mousedown on the progressbar and then drag, i assume they switch to a window event?

I know there is easier solutions out there, but i wanted to do things from scratch. 

I guess i could try that plugin and be more lazy or wise!

But just looking for feedback, my friend seems to have fixed my problem, however he wont share the solution.

Comment: I was able to solve it by using the window eventlisteners for the mousemove and the mouse up, after that it was good!